# Структура БД MySQL

Tags: sql, проектирование, база-данных, mysql

Возник вопрос при создании БД. Структура работы следующая:

```
Линия 1
    --Участок 1
        -- оборудования 1
        -- оборудования 2
        -- оборудования n
    --Участок 2 
        -- оборудования 3
Линия 2 
    --Участок 3
        -- оборудования 4
Линия 3
```

Есть товары. Один и тот же товар может быть во всех оборудованиях с разным количеством. У товара есть категория, категория может быть только одна (у товара). Есть проблема: категория товаров может иметь две единицы измерения: штуки и метры. Также товар может хранится на 1 или 2-х складах, в разных количествах. Линии друг с другом не связаны, точно так же участки и оборудования.

Хочу сделать вывод в таком формате:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Название|Категория|Оборудывания |К-во|Участок |Линия |Склад 1| Склад 2|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
товар1  |первая   |оборудывание1| 3шт|Участок1|Линия1|  12   |0   | 
                  |оборудывание2| 1шт|Участок2|Линия2|        | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мою структуру создания БД. И что здесь нужно изменить, по вашему мнению. **Структура:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2552d4/1

Comment: Такой огромный SQL лучше перенести на [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/), либо использовать другие представления: [IDEF1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF1X) или [ERD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, какие комментарии вы ждете по структуре. Если она вас устраивает, то по виду нормальная структура.
Если вы хотите поменять структуру как-то для этого отчета, то структура тут ни при чем. Несвязанные друг с другом данные вы хотите вывести в одну табличку. На sql'е это можно сделать с шаманством типа вычисления номера строки через row_num() и "расположением рядом", все то же самое можно сделать двумя запросами и в коде отстраивать отчет как угодно.

Если говорить про структуру вообще, то тут такие общие комментарии:

1. Цена - может меняться, и нужна будет вся история изменения цен. Кроме того, типов цен может быть несколько.
2. Единицы измерения не должны быть привязаны к категориям. Единица измерения - это свойство товара. У товара могут быть одновременно несколько единиц измерения как с преобразованием одних в другие по коэффициенту (коробка = 10 шт), так непреобразуемые, как у вас (шт. и метры). Тут нужна подчиненная таблица "единицы измерения товара" (spare_id, property_id, ...). И далее единицу измерения надо тянуть через все документы, остатки и т.д., где есть количество. Т.е. количество в отрыве от единицы измерения смысла не имеет.

Comment: "Несвязанные друг с другом данные вы хотите вывести в одну табличку" - но почему, у меня получается товар связаный с оборудываниям, а оборудывания связано с участком, а участок связаный с линией. Не совсем понятно про: Цена - может меняться, и нужна будет вся история изменения цен. Цена будет только в одной валюте.

Comment: @depredator, как у вас связаны "оборудования" и "склады"? Речь была про оптовые, розничные, закупочные цены, не про валюты. Цены меняются. Даже если вам не нужна история изменения цен (в конце концов будет нужна), цены должны быть в отдельной таблице.  
N.B. это **общие** комментарии, которые относятся не к конкретно вашей задаче (вы ее не описали), а вообще к системам учета.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а как лучше сделать такую связь. Товар должен иметь одну категория, и в тоже время товар может присутствувать на разных оборудываниях (минимум на одном). И каждое оборудывания может иметь категорию. Просто нужно построить будет список категорий, которые входят в данное оборудывание. Я сделал две связи, не знаю, верно или нет: `equipment_category` и `equipment_spares`.

Comment: @depredator, у вас "товар входит в категорию" и "товар входит в оборудование". Таким образом вам нужно через товар получить связь категорий и оборудования. поэтому equipment_spares и catergory_spares. связываете их по товару и получаете "многие ко многим" - категории и оборудования.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо, вроде бы сделал.

    SELECT DISTINCT categories.category_id, categories.name FROM categories, spares, equipment_spares
 WHERE equipment_spares.equipment_id = 1 
 AND spares.spares_id = equipment_spares.spares_id
 AND categories.category_id = spares.category_id

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,Возникла такая ситуация, некоторые товары будут относится до всех оборудываний(общий товар). В данный момент оборудываний более 450 записей. Как поступать в данной ситуации ? Мое решения NULL в внешним ключе.

Comment: @depredator, скорее всего, это не единственное решение, а потому плохое. надо исходить из постановки задачи, т.е. если товар относится ко всем текущим оборудованиям (если честно, я не очень понимаю формулировку), а к новым относиться не будет, то 450 записей в таблице связи погоды не делают, ничего страшного в них нет. Если товар будет относиться всегда ко всем оборудованиям (к новым тоже), то, возможно, стоит выделить такой товар каким-то дополнительным признаком.  
Нельзя допускать, чтоб особенности хранения в субд имели какой-то неочевидный смысл.